# How to show other point property in bubble highcharts using tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm searching for a way to show the `name` property using a tool-tip, this way does not work.

**Property plotOptions:**

```
 ...,
    plotOptions : {
        bubble : {
            tooltip : {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                pointFormat : '{point.x} fatalities, {point.y} injured, {point.z}  total, {point.name} New Prop'

            }
        }
    },...
```

**Property Series**

```
...series: [{
        data: [[97,36,79,{name:'a'}],[94,74,60,{name:'a'}],[68,76,58,{name:'a'}],[64,87,56,{name:'a'}],[68,27,73,{name:'a'}],[74,99,42,{name:'a'}],[7,93,87,{name:'a'}],[51,69,40,{name:'a'}],[38,23,33,{name:'a'}],[57,86,31,{name:'a'}]]
    },...
```

[Try code here](http://jsfiddle.net/4uNP7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not formatted properly.

This:

```
[97,36,79,{name:'a'}]
```

Needs to be this:

```
{x:97,y:36,z:79,name:'a'}
```